# Dynamics 365 unexpected error

Tags: dynamics-crm

When creating a case I get the below error.

> Access Error The system could not log you on. This could be because
>   your user record or the business unit you belong to has been disabled
>   in Microsoft Dynamics 365. If you contact support, please provide the
>   technical details.

This occurred shortly after deleting the CRM Admin user and creating a new CRM Admin user in the Office 365 users screen.

The more technical message is

> The user with
>   SystemUserId=bb51ba1c-66e8-4dc1-82ca-cb64e25f3ff9 in
>   OrganizationContext=7e061672-3a31-4588-9770-9f94711c7f09 is
>   disabledDetail.

Comment: Your question is not related to software development and therefore off-topic here. You can post your issue on the appropriate Microsoft forum or ask MS Support.

Answer (score 2):

The error message is saying that the user with that ID is disabled so the first thing to do would be to open that record and check which user it is.

To do that, use the URL below but replace the xx's and the yourregion part of the url (I've already added your user id).

```
https://xxxxxxxx.yourregion.dynamics.com/main.aspx?etc=8&extraqs=&histKey=952109180&id={bb51ba1c-66e8-4dc1-82ca-cb64e25f3ff9}&newWindow=true&pagetype=entityrecord
```

You will then need to enable that user or resolve problems from there.

I would also check that you don't have any plugins or workflows which have been setup to run as that user when creating a case.